# Something is wrapping elements in <strong><strong></strong></strong>

Tags: html

I have a web page that for some reason, children of elements with itemprop attributes are being wrapped in `&lt;strong&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;`  If you view the source of the page, those <strong> aren't there.  If you inspect an element, the `&lt;strong&gt;` tags are in the DOM.  If I disable JavaScript and load the page, those <strong> aren't visible when you view source but they are there if you inspect one of the elements that is wrapped in them.

Here's one of the pages where this is (was) happening: (as our product editors fix their mistakes this issue won't be visible anymore) https://www.rockymountainatvmc.com/p/831/41710/Alpinestars-Bionic-Neck-Support-Pro?term=bionic+neck+support+pro (Scroll down and click on the Customer Reviews tab)  The customer comment paragraphs are not supposed to be bold and if you view source they are not but if you right click on one of those bold paragraphs and click inspect element the paragraph it is double wrapped in strong tags.

How do I find out how these tags are being injected into the DOM?  I already tried break on subtree modification but nothing happens when I do that.

Thanks

Here's the image one of the comments requested:

[image]

The strong tags are not there if you view the source for the page, they are only in the DOM.

Comment: they are not beeing injected. But wich elements on your shop are you talking about?

Comment: All children of elements with itemprop attribute.

Comment: may you add an image, I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: i guess you are doing it via some script, wrapping `<span class="first">` with <strong>, twice

Comment: I checked your source page, there is some wrong tag displaying ``<Strong>``  you may want to make it lower case?

Comment: base.js has some annotation code that is probably doing this.  Since it's minified it's really hard to tell exactly what's going on.  Do you have the unminified sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it happens even with JS disabled, I think that means that somewhere in your code above that point, you have stray `<strong>` tags that aren't closed, and the browser is trying to deal with them.  I think I see a couple - take a look.

Comment: Hey, you are right, I found two opening Strong tags with capital S without closing tags.  Thanks, I'll accept this answer as soon as I'm allowed to (2 minutes from now)